# Adjusting image size in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have an image that's being displayed , the image should be displayed taking up the maximum
possible part of the window and adjusting to the resizing of the window, but at the same time the ratio of the width of the image to its height should remain unchanged (should not change image aspect ratio).

How can this be made ?

Here is the code that I have written :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ImageShuffle extends JFrame {
JLabel label;
public ImageShuffle(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("TOKYO.gif"));
    label = new JLabel(image);
    this.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ImageShuffle();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a custom component, like this, in the overridden `paintComponent`, do all the calculation for the new scale and draw the image.

This code example will show an image that is scaled to fit the component size, keeping its aspect ratio, and centered horizontally or vertically in the exceeding space.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestAutoResizeImage extends JComponent {
    protected BufferedImage img;
    public TestAutoResizeImage() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        img=ImageIO.read(new URL("https://i.imgur.com/dsBJr4C.png"));
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        //Using image size as preferred size
        return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        //Using image size as minimum size
        return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        //Compute scaling for both axis according to current component size
        //then use the lower value
        double scaleX=getWidth()*1.0/img.getWidth();
        double scaleY=getHeight()*1.0/img.getHeight();
        double scale=Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

        //Center the image on the axis with greater scale
        double offsetX=(getWidth()-scale*img.getWidth())/2.0;
        double offsetY=(getHeight()-scale*img.getHeight())/2.0;

        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g.create();

        //This gives a better quality in upscaling, but also slow down the repainting, remove it if the resizing not responsive enough
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
        
        //We must consider the current possible transform before applying our scaling
        //Current transform
        AffineTransform at=g2.getTransform();
        //Translate to center
        at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(offsetX, offsetY));
        //Scale image
        at.concatenate(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
        
        g2.setTransform(at);
        //Paint the transformed image
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        
        g2.dispose();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Autoresize image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new TestAutoResizeImage());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `Graphics#create` and `Graphics#dispose`.  This will create a copy of the graphics context, which you can then manipulate (ie change the transform) and then, when you don't need it any more, dispose of it and release any resources it was maintaining - this will leave the original context unchanged (I mean the properties, all the drawing still exists)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I was thinking about it, now I did. I'm just wondering, what is the overhead of creating a new Graphics instead of restoring its state?

Comment: From what I understand, not a lot - especially if you making a lot of changes to the context, much easier to create/dispose than to try and remember how to undo all the modifications.  Also forget to mention that `paintComponent` will be called ALOT while the component is been resized, so rescaling the image might cause delays/issues - which is where I might consider using a "low quality" scale until I can ascertain the the operation has stopped and then do a "high quality" scale - but that's probably beyond the scope of the question ;)

Comment: @roco I should mention that create/dispose only effects the "properties" of the context, it doesn't create another "buffer" or what ever is been used behind the scenes ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I checked the code, just a bunch of variables copied, but no special resources allocated.